# Trying to give permission to Apache on Dropbox folder via Alias on Windows

Tags: windows, apache, permissions, xampp, dropbox

Im trying to setup a alias to dropbox using Xampp on windows 7.

I gave recursive full access permission to "Everyone" on C: and D: but I'm still getting a 403 Forbidden error on apache.

Dropbox is on C:\Users\João\Dropbox and Xampp is on D:\xampp

My alias is
Alias /pp C:/Users/João/Dropbox/pp

The alias is working since I got a 403 and not a 404 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me.

Make Symbol link to dropbox. In command line promt

> **`mklink /D D:\xampp\path-to-the-www-root C:\Users\João\Dropbox\YourProject`**

Point xampp to dirrectory in www-root and turn on FollowSymLinks (for Apache)